# How can I check that a document is entirely in American or British English?

Tags: documents, english, grammar

I'm not a native speaker and during writing, I have some candidates like "grey"'/"gray" that I will always mix up.

So sometimes, when I write papers with colleagues (e.g. in LaTeX or plain text), we stick to either American or British English. However, as a final step I want to ensure that we don't end up mixing both flavors.

Comment: I would be careful about an automated system - I am English - gray can be used and I tend to use ize - and they are correct for non US English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take data from this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences):

and stup a script to check automatically the text.

You could have a look at this open office extension as well http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/en_US-dict

Comment: watch out for this: [same word different meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_words_having_different_meanings_in_American_and_British_English)